# How to prevent duplicate id in creating objects from SPA? Or should I stay with the db?

Tags: postgresql, go, single-page-application

I have a react app that fetches data from golang api which queries data from postgres database. One of my models is deeply nested JSON so I used JSONB datatype in postgres.

```
CREATE table rules (
    id serial primary key,
    rule jsonb
);
```

In golang, I have the structure

```
type Rule struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    ...succeeding fields are deeply nested data
}
```

And in the SPA I have the model

```
interface Rule {
    id number
    name string
    ....same as from the golang api model
}
```

To create a new `Rule` object in the SPA, I assign `0` to `id`. The newly created rule is sent to golang rest api. Then in the api, I first ask the postgres database for the next value for the serial id (using POSTGRES `nextval`), assign that acquired id into the Rule struct ID field,

```
nextValidId := <result of nextval>
rule.ID = nextValidId
```

JSON marshal the rule object then insert to db

```
ruleBytes, _ := json.Marshal(rule)
INSERT INTO rules_table VALUES (<nextValidId>, <ruleBytes>);
```

This way I avoided duplicate ids which may happen if an SPA is handling the Id generation. However, I find my method somewhat complicated already. I know I can generate ids from SPA too but how do I avoid duplicated ids without using the method I used above? or am I overthinking things?

Update1:
I also thought about adding another Rule struct in golang without the `ID` field so that I don't have to use `nextval` just to put the id inside the JSON, but is it a good programming design to have multiple models for inserting and retrieving from db and another model for response to the SPA?

Comment: Use insert with the returning clause. `INSERT INTO rules_table (rule) VALUES (<ruleBytes>) RETURNING id;`, execute this query with Go's QueryRow and then call Scan on the resulting row to get the id.

Comment: if I use the on returning clause, that means after inserting the data, I quickly have to update it to put the generated id into the JSON

Comment: Why would you need it in the json column if it is already in its own column, why duplicate the data?

Comment: id need to be sent back to SPA user to enable delete and edit for specific `rule`. I put it inside the Rule model. Or are you suggesting that the model should not contain the id field?

Comment: The model, yes. The json going out to the client, yes. The json column in the db, no.

Comment: if we look at the response to user, a rule object contains its id. In golang the struct contains the id. Yes duplication happens, any alternative?

Comment: I'm not talking about the duplication of the rule's representation across the languages. I'm talking about the duplication of data in the database.

Comment: oh so I really have to create another struct without the id field, this struct is meant to be json marshalled then inserted to db? or should I just marshal my existing struct with the id field even though the value in that field is not the same as that generated by the db?

Comment: Something like this is what I had in mind: https://play.golang.org/p/rtenP2c_xph

Comment: If, however, you still want the id to be also in the json column, then you can use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to get the serial's next value and then concatenate it with the json in the insert.

Comment: okay, I got it. I was just thinking too much before that my rule json inside the db has an id field which is not the same as the one generated by the db. I think assigning the id field from the db table to the unmarshalled rule is better

Answer (score 0):

Let the database generate the new id since that's exactly [`SERIAL` types are for in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

In golang, you can insert a new record and retrieve the generated id by using [`sql.DB.QueryRow(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) and `.Scan()` using an [insert statement with a `RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html), e.g.:

```
var newId int
query := "INSERT INTO rules (rule) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id"
err := db.QueryRow(query, newRule).Scan(&newId)
// TODO: check err
log.Printf("newId=%d", newId)
```